# Who is user3439894 ? I want to thank him/her for https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235794/283681 in real life

Tags: discussion

I found this mystery user in our community very intriguing, after looking at his/her stats.

Contributions since 21st Feb 2015 and especially [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235794/283681).

I see recent activity too, so kindly reach out at https://DVNSH.com in real life so that I can share my gratefulness.

Comment: This user has helped me with his comments several times too.

Comment: Agreed! I have had some differences of opinion with *894*, but he has also been hugely helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for asking this. The way to contact people on the site is to use the profile look up tools. Not everyone discloses their emails or phones or web pages, but some do.

Within the site, the best way to “thank” someone is to share links to their answers, edit (if you’re sure you are making a post better - commenting first if you need an OK to make a big edit), and awarding them bounties.

Also - if someone is here in an anonymous / not easily traceable, consider that they may have reasons to manage their identity - so be sure you are not doxxing someone unintentionally by researching / disclosing information that’s not publicly available or shared by a person / account.

In your case, the profile is set up to share minimum data, so you might need to be patient for them to see and possibly decline politely your generous offer to make contact with them.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894

I, too, appreciate their contributions here greatly. We should be lucky to have more people like them here. The same goes with people like you that take the time to recognize others for being useful and helpful.